# Filtering data in python

Tags: python, loops

I am working on a web crawler for python that gathers information on posts by users on a site and compares their scores for posts all provided users participate in. It is currently structured so that I receive the following data:

`results` is a dictionary indexed by username that contains dictionaries of each user's history in a `post`, `points` key value structure.

`common` is a list that starts with all the posts in the dictionary of the first user in results. This list should be filtered down to only the posts all users have in common

`points` is a dictionary indexed by username that keeps a running total of points on shared posts.

My filtering code is below:

```
common = list(results.values()[0].keys())

for user in results:
    for post_hash in common:
        if post_hash not in results[user]:
            common.remove(post_hash)
        else:
            points[user] += results[user][post_hash]
```

The issue I'm encountering is that this doesn't actually filter out posts that aren't shared, and thus, doesn't provide accurate point values.

What am I doing wrong with my structure, and is there any easier way to find only the common posts?

Comment: can you post copy of your data structure for us to look at?  Just a small sample of two users + posts and points would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have two issues:

1. Using a list for `common` means that when you remove an item via `common.remove`, it will only remove the first item it finds (there could be more)
2. You're not just adding points for posts shared by all users - you're adding points for users as you encounter them - before you know if that post is shared by everyone or not

Without some actual data to play with, it's a little difficult to write working code, but try this:

```
# this should give us a list of posts shared by all users
common = set.intersection(*[set(k.keys()) for k in results.values()])

# there's probably a more efficient (functional) way of summing the points 
# by user instead of looping, but simple is good.
for user in results:
    for post_hash in common:
        points[user] += results[user][post_hash]
```

Comment: This works great! Using common as a list shouldn't have been an issue since when I initially process each user's data, I total points for each post, but the set intersections works even better, and much more efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: @Neomang Yes, it works, but it is not efficient as you making it out to be. There is a list comp while evaluating `common`. *All* your posts will be in memory simultaneously for no reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools

iterable = (v.keys() for v in results.values())
common = funtools.reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, iterable)
points = {user: sum(posts[post] for post in common) for user,posts in results.items()}
```

See if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. When I use that, I get the following error:
    `common = list(fn.reduce(op.or_, iterable))
        TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'`

Comment: @Neomang Just edited it. If it works, it will be very efficient as there are no intermediate data structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
posts = []
# Create an array of all the post hashes
for p in results.values():
    posts.extend(p.keys())

# use Counter to create a dictionary like object that where the key
# is the post hash and the value is the number of occurrences
posts = Counter(posts)
for user in results:
    # Reduce only the posts that show up more than once.
    points[user] = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, (post for post in user if posts[post] > 1))
```